# Largest prime number less than a power of $10.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, induction

I just thought of this problem, I don't know if this is even possible using elementary methods. It goes as follows:

Let $p$ be the largest prime number less than $10^k.$ What is the smallest $k\geq 2$ such that $p$ does not contain the digit $9$ in its decimal representation? If there is no such $k$, prove that $p$ will always contain the digit $9$?

Now, my first thought is that if $p$ always contain the digit $9,$ there is some inductive argument to be made. However, I do not even know if that is true (I do feel that it most likely is, especially since the number of $9$s seems to increase on average as $k$ increases.)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it is true or not. However, if I had to guess, I would assume that there is such a $k$. My intuition is because there are arbitrarily large gaps in the prime numbers that if one of these large gaps starts with a prime number not containing a $9$, then it is likely that there is a power of $10$ before the next prime. This in no means is a proof, but rather just my intuition and guess that it would be correct.

Comment: @StevenCreech well the question would be whether these arbitrary large gaps increase faster than $\frac{1}{10}$ the number of digits

Comment: Note that all the numbers from $10^{k}-10^{k-1}$ up to $10^{k}-1$ do contain digit nines.

Comment: It would mean that there is no prime $p$ such that $10^k \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{10}}} \right) \le p < 10^k$, but it is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results) that there is at least one prime like that.

Comment: For large enough $n,$ there is always a prime between $n$ and $10/9.$ It might even be true for $n\geq 90,$ and then the answer would be $p$ always has a $9$ as the first digit. In any event, there can be at most finitely many $k.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews how does that show that there is only finitely many $k$? If $9$ is always the first digit, then there is infinitely many $k,$ correct?

Comment: @MandelBroccoli Finitely many $k$ so that the largest prime below $10^k$ does not contain the digit $9$.

Comment: @MandelBroccoli it is the opposite. For some number $M$, there is a prime in $[9N/10,N]$ for all $N \ge M$. So then, let $k$ be any integer s.t. $10^k > M$. Then there is a prime between $9×10^{k-1}$ and $10^k$ i.e., its most significant digit is a $9$.

Comment: @Gary Oh, ok, but that does not show that there is no such $k,$ correct? Only that there are at most finitely many.

Comment: If you look at my comment above, you can work out that the only cases you probably have to check by hand are $k=2,3$. Indeed by the 1998 result of Dusart, there is at least one prime $p$ such that $$
10^k \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{10}}} \right) < p \le \left( {1 + \frac{1}{{2\log ^2 \left( {10^k \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{10}}} \right)} \right)}}} \right)10^k \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{10}}} \right) < 10^k 
$$ whenever $k\geq 4$.

Comment: Largest $k$-digit prime is tabulated at https://oeis.org/A003618 – lots of nines there.

Comment: The prime number theorem together with inspection for the very small cases establishes easily that the largest prime less than $10^k$ begins with digit $9$ for every $k\ge 2$. For the smallest prime larger than $10^k$, the siutation is different and the question much more interesting.